# How to print this API response data in React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I want to print this data on my mobile screen but it shows me nothing when I write the code from this response:

[image: my response from api]

This is my code:

```
    const [data, setData] = useState('')
      useEffect(() => {
        getData()
    
      }, [])
 const getData = async () => {

    fetch(`${urldemo}blog/${slug}?token=${user_token}`, {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    })

      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        setLoading(false);
        setData([...data, ...responseJson.result]);  
        console.log("log for Exploreblogs =====>", responseJson.result)

      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }
```

This is my return code where I am stuck:

```
         const renderItem = ({ item }) => {
    
        return (
          <ScrollView style={[styles.footer, {
            backgroundColor: "white"
            // colors.background
          }]}>
    
            <Card style={{ marginHorizontal: 20, }}>
              <Card.Cover style={{ marginVertical: 10, borderRadius: 10, height: 200, }}
                source={require('../../../assets/imagehere.png')} />
    
              <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between' }}>
    
                <Image
                  source={require('../../../assets/news9.png')} />
    
                <Text style={{ textAlign: 'right', color: "orange" }}>
                  {item.short_description}
    
                </Text>
              </View>
              <Text style={{ textAlign: 'center', color: "black", fontSize: 24 }}>
                {item.description}
    
              </Text>
    
              <View style={{
                justifyContent: "space-between",
                flexDirection: "row",
                marginHorizontal: 10
              }}>
                <View style={{ flexDirection: "row" }}>
    
                  <Text style={{ color: "green" }}>4hrs ago</Text>
                  <Text style={{ color: "green" }}> ~ 5 min read</Text>
                </View>
    
                <View style={{ flexDirection: "row" }}>
                  <Image
                    source={require('../../../assets/comment.png')} />
                  <Image style={{ marginHorizontal: 10 }}
                    source={require('../../../assets/shae.png')} />
                  <Image
                    source={require('../../../assets/saved.png')} />
                </View>
              </View>
            </Card>
    
            {/* <Text style={{
              textAlign: 'left', color: "grey", fontSize: 16,
              marginHorizontal: 20, marginVertical: 20
            }}>
             {item.title}
            </Text> */}
    
            <Image style={{ marginHorizontal: 20, width: "90%", borderRadius: 10 }}
              source={require('../../../assets/exnews.png')} />
            <Text style={{ marginHorizontal: 20 }}>{item.description}</Text>
    
    
            <Text style={{
              textAlign: 'left', color: "grey", fontSize: 16,
              marginHorizontal: 20, marginVertical: 20
            }}>
              {item.short_description}
            </Text>
    
    
    
          </ScrollView>
        );
      }
    return (
        <TouchableOpacity >
          {/* <BlogsHeader />
          
          */}
    
          <Animatable.View
    
            animation="zoomIn" >
    
            <View style={{
              flexDirection: 'row',
              flexWrap: 'wrap',
              justifyContent: 'space-between',
              backgroundColor: 'white',
              height: 45,
            }}>
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Blogs')}>
                <Image style={{
                  color: 'black',
                  marginTop: 15,
                  tintColor: 'orange'
                }}
                  source={require('../../../assets/backicon.png')}
                />
              </TouchableOpacity>
    
              <Text style={{
                fontSize: 15,
                color: '#FF7F23',
                textAlign: "center",
                marginTop: 15,
              }}
              > Blogs</Text>
    
              <Image style={{ color: 'black', marginTop: 15, alignSelf: 'center', }}
                source={require('../../../assets/avatar.png')}
              />
            </View>
    
            {isLoading ? <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#FF8025" /> : (
              <FlatList
                style={styles.container}
                data={data}
                renderItem={renderItem}
                keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
    
              />
            )
            }
          </Animatable.View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      )
```

I have used Flatlist for Item.
I just want to print my response data on my mobile screen but it didn't
work for me

I get following error message in the console output:

> [TypeError: Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance. In order to be iterable, non-array objects must have a Symbol.iterator method.]

Comment: Do you have console errors? If you have defined `getData()` after the call in `useEffect` it should be undefined.

Comment: @jonrsharpe yes this is the error in console
[TypeError: Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance.
In order to be iterable, non-array objects must have a [Symbol.iterator]() method.]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with this line:

```
setData([...data, ...responseJson.result]);
```

I'm assuming `responseJson.result` is an object, in which case this won't work since you can't spread an object into an array, [at least in the way you intend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45285171/spread-operator-converting-objects-to-array).

This should work for you though:

```
const [data, setData] = useState({}) // Use object instead

// Other stuff

setData({...data, ...responseJson.result}); // Spread to object instead.
```

Alternatively, consider checking out [these solutions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/is_not_iterable) e.g. `for...of` or `Object.keys()/entries()/...`.

Otherwise, you would need to post the value `responseJson.result` for more troubleshooting.

Comment: it didn't work for me . i have response from API but it is not print on mobile screen

Comment: Any errors? Also, I'd have to see more of the return code, since you use `item` there so I can't tell how you're even using `data`.

Comment: Placzek I updated the above code

Comment: @ABDULLAH Can you show the error you get after changing the code (If there is any)? Also, please show a response from the api so we can get some kind of idea of what it looks like.

Comment: you can see the error in the above picture. Errors are below in the picture

Comment: @ABDULLAH see [this snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@razermoon/bruh) for a working example. The main thing I did (apart from my first fix) is change to this `data={[data]}`.